# Error: module `string` is in file 'std/c/string.d' which cannot be read

Tags: compiler-errors, d, dmd

I am following [this guide](https://github.com/buggins/dlangui/wiki/Getting-Started) for dlangui, but when I run `dub run`, I get the error `Error: module 'string' is in file 'std/c/string.d' which cannot be read`

Comment: what version of everything do you have? Like does your dub.json or whatever literally list `"dlangui": "0.6.11"` like the example, or is it auto updated to something newer? it sounds like a version mismatch between stdlib and the dependency library. (it lists a minimum dmd version, but if the library hasn't been updated to remove the std.c.string usage, there's a max version too - std.c.string has been replaced with core.stdc.string a long time ago!)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe dlangui": "0.9.178"

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe dmd: v2.082.0, dub: 1.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long to get back to you on this.

But the version numbers confirmed this was a version thing: this commit fixes the issue upstream https://github.com/buggins/dlangui/commit/18286dc6596c5a06efbb21c1ce524a3fd2d467e8

And it was released in dlangui 0.9.179 - one version ahead what you were using. And it just came out yesterday! So if you try again now it should be fine.